# Drupal commerce order total ignore changed unit price

Tags: rules, commerce

I have problem with commerce order total counting.

Every product has two prices (two fields). One price for everybody and second for exact role. I have rule which change prices if user with exact role is logged in.

When i browse product with exact role all prices are ok. If i add some product to cart a go to my cart product prices and total price is still good. But when i go to checkout total price is set to 0.

In checkout are all products with good price but total price is 0.

Rule for changing price is simple:

```
event: calculate product price
condition: user role
action: set a data value (commerce-line-item:commerce-unit-price -> second price field)
```

Do anybody know what could be wrong? Thanks for every advice.

Comment: What version of commerce do you use?

Comment: I have the same issue with commerce 7.x-1.10. See the bug description: https://www.drupal.org/node/2215783

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to downgrade rules to v 2.7. For more details look at https://www.drupal.org/node/2408705

> Important: Rules 2.8 has a critical regression that causes checkout
>   rules to not work. Follow #2403851: Commerce pricing rule not working
>   for more details, and downgrade to 2.7 for now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just checked and I use commerce 7.x-1.9 and rules 7.x-2.7. Does it work if you use commerce 7.x-1.10 and rules 7.x-2.7? Do you use same rule like me?

Comment: In my working example I use another rule action: "Multiply the unit price by some amount".

In your case it's better to use action "Set the unit price to a specific amount".

NOTICE: you should add a rule condition "Entity has a field" with the field to your "second price field". Otherwise you can't see this field in fields list inside the action "Set the unit price to a specific amount".

Comment: I was using commerce-7.x-1.11 and rules-7.x-2.8 in Drupal 7 and met the same trouble, as on 2015-02-01. Some (or all?) Rules that work on each line-item did not work in checkout; the prices that are modified with a custom Rule for each line-item do not propagate to the checkout.   Downgrading Rules to 7.x-2.7, as suggested, worked immediately.  Ta!

Comment: @PeterLozovitskiy Thanks a lot. Your suggested action solved my problem.

Comment: Does Rules 2.9 work?

Comment: @jackrabbithanna I don't know. Could you please try and let us know?

Comment: Sure enough does work in 2.9, seems to be fixed